# Roundoff number to greater value in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to roundoff my number to greater value. for example if i have 234 i want to make it 300 and 4436 to 5000. I have tried it but i can roundoff my value not in hundred and thousants but in tens. like i have a value 7771 it roundoff to 7900 or 7800 but i want it in 8000.

```
int temp = lroundf([[arrayPercentage objectAtIndex:i]floatValue]);
maxPer = (((temp + 10)/10))*10;
```

Comment: what range of numbers do you need to round up? Just numbers in the hundreds or thousands? Tens of thousands? Millions? How general does the method need to be?

Comment: there is no specific range. but most probably it will be in thousands .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
-(void)roundUpNumber:(NSInteger) num {
    NSInteger numLength = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",num] length];
    NSInteger newNum = ceil(num/pow(10,numLength-1)) * pow(10,numLength -1);
    NSLog(@"%ld",newNum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int num, count = 0;
    int originalNumber = 7771;

    num = originalNumber;
    while (num) {
        num = num/10;
        count ++;
    }

    int power = pow(10,(count -1));

    int firstDigit = originalNumber / power;


    int finalNumber = (firstDigit + 1)*  power;

    NSLog(@"final result : %d",finalNumber);
```